# List WordPress Child Pages With Thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, function, children

I am trying to list the children of a WordPress page - which is easy and is provided by their documentation. However, I can't seem to find how to include the set page thumbnail above each page name.

The code is provided here to list each name:

```
<ul>
  <?php
  global $id;
  wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$id&show_date=modified
  &date_format=$date_format"); ?>
</ul>
```

and the documentation for that function is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Thanks a lot

Comment: `wp_list_pages` does not support page thumbnails AFAIK.

Comment: Is there another possible way to do it then? Maybe with a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your functions.php file, paste this in there if its not already there..

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

then visit each of your pages, on the right hand side, you will have a new meta box,
called "**Featured Image**" you can click the link to open your media library, from there select the image you want to use as the featured image, ( page - thumbnail )

do this for each of the pages you want to show a thumbnail for..

then possibly create a new page template?

adding the code below to loop through the pages and pull out the image for each..

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'page','post_status'=>'publish')
// The Query
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) :
           the_post_thumbnail();
        else:
           echo the_title();
        endif;
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

very rough guide, but you get the just of it..? 
more on [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

[Marty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148174/marty)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. It was that loop code that I was wondering about. I'll be trying this tomorrow but it looks like it should work.